# Why 'hwclock' command applies a positive offset for local time, while the 'date' command applies a negative offset?

Tags: linux, date, timezone, clock

I am having some problems working with timezones. Can someone please explain these results to me? Why does the `hwclock` command apply a positive offset for local time, while the `date` command applies a negative offset?

```
$> export TZ=BRA+2
$> date
Tue Jan 31 18:22:45 BRA 2017
$> date -u
Tue Jan 31 20:22:48 UTC 2017
$> hwclock --systohc
$> hwclock -l
Tue Jan 31 18:23:04 2017  0.000000 seconds
$> hwclock -u
Tue Jan 31 16:23:12 2017  0.000000 seconds
$> hwclock --systohc --utc
$> hwclock -l
Tue Jan 31 20:23:31 2017  0.000000 seconds
$> hwclock -u
Tue Jan 31 18:23:34 2017  0.000000 seconds
```

Comment: Two different programmers?  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your confusion is in the use of the `-l` and `-u` for `hwclock`.

> Note that using the --utc or --localtime options with the hwclock command does not mean you are displaying the hardware clock time in UTC or local time.

What this means is that when you run:

```
hwclock -u
```

You are not displaying the time in utc, you are telling the system to interpret the hwclock in UTC, and vice-versa with `-l`.

From the man page:

```
-u, --utc
--localtime
Indicates that the Hardware Clock is kept in Coordinated Universal
Time or local time, respectively. It is your choice whether to keep
your clock in UTC or local time, but nothing in the clock tells
which you've chosen. So this option is how you give that information
to hwclock. If you specify the wrong one of these options (or
specify neither and take a wrong default), both setting and querying
of the Hardware Clock will be messed up.

If you specify neither --utc nor --localtime , the default is whichever
was specified the last time hwclock was used to set the clock (i.e.
hwclock was successfully run with the --set, --systohc, or --adjust
options), as recorded in the adjtime file. If the adjtime file
doesn't exist, the default is local time.
```

([Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Configuring_the_Date_and_Time-hwclock.html))